# Progress is not shown when I navigate to another activity and return to same activity but doinbackground process is running

Tags: android

Let me explain issue:
1. I have a activity inside my app which is contains do in background process for  perticuler task.
2. Inside pre execute process i set progress is visible on the top header of activity and inside post execute i set its gone.
3. But when i navigate to another activity and return to same activity,my progress is not visible but background process still running.
  how can i solve this problem?

[I notify the progress inside black circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Z02N.png)
  Below is my code :

```
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();           
        progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);   
        //showDialog();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        upload(_file,_dir,this);
        return null;
    }
            @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //dismissDialog();
        uploadingCompleted(_uploadResult,_file);
        progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
```

Comment: Show the full code. Is the `AsyncTask` an inner class in your `Activity`?

Comment: does using view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) instead of GONE cause the same thing ?

Comment: No,its not working using View.INVISIBLE

Comment: How do you know your background thread complete?

Comment: @Rgv: The progress should be handled in the code if you know your background process is complete or not.

Answer (score 0):

when you return to first activity its oncreate method run again and because you set visibility to gone it will be hidden .you should in oncreate method check is your AsyncTask running? if it is running set visibility to visible else set it to gone

Comment: Thanks,but how can I check that my Async Task is running.I  can try with boolean value but its not working so please give me a solution for checking Async Task running or not?

Comment: you can set a valiable in onPreExecute() to false and set it to true in onPostExecute and check it for true in oncreate